# How to start applications with out any database in django

Tags: python, django

I am trying to start Django runserver without any database setting. 
currently I have tried setting the db engine as dummy.

python manage.py runserver is able to start ok.

But the webpage is not coming up properly and it is showing some python exceptions which look like it is looking for database tables for the models classes i have written and it is trying to connect to some db for my model classes.

Can someone give me solution for this problem. I wan my web page to work without any db to configure. and still my model classes works ok.

Additional Information on the above :
Thanks for your quick replies. I have also tried setting empty values in Database settings. The requirement of the project is to start the website without any database running. The website project is an old system build on django 1.1 and was extensively using oracle so all its model classes where using oracle. But I have to basically retire oracle database from the site project and override the save methods to dump to external file and send to other system using tcp connection on the fly.

And we do not have to use any single database in our production environment.

The error I an getting in the webpage is as follows, which will help you guys to think about the possible problems. Errors:

File "/home/AK/trunk/python/portal/../portal/utils/views.py", line 94, in init self.get_results(request, max_rows)

File "/home/AK/trunk/python/portal/../portal/utils/views.py", line 140, in get_results self.results_count = paginator.count

File "/usr/lib64/python2.6/site-packages/django/core/paginator.py", line 48, in _get_count self._count = self.object_list.count()

File "/usr/lib64/python2.6/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py", line 292, in count return self.query.get_count()

File "/usr/lib64/python2.6/site-packages/django/db/models/sql/query.py", line 376, in get_count number = obj.get_aggregation()[None]

File "/usr/lib64/python2.6/site-packages/django/db/models/sql/query.py", line 348, in get_aggregation result = query.execute_sql(SINGLE)

File "/usr/lib64/python2.6/site-packages/django/db/models/sql/query.py", line 2360, in execute_sql sql, params = self.as_sql()

File "/usr/lib64/python2.6/site-packages/django/db/models/sql/query.py", line 401, in as_sql from_, f_params = self.get_from_clause()

File "/usr/lib64/python2.6/site-packages/django/db/models/sql/query.py", line 861, in get_from_clause result.append('%s%s%s' % (connector, qn(name), alias_str))

File "/usr/lib64/python2.6/site-packages/django/db/models/sql/query.py", line 175, in quote_name_unless_alias r = self.connection.ops.quote_name(name)

File "/usr/lib64/python2.6/site-packages/django/db/backends/dummy/base.py", line 15, in complain raise ImproperlyConfigured, "You haven't set the DATABASE_ENGINE setting yet."

ImproperlyConfigured: You haven't set the DATABASE_ENGINE setting yet.

thanks

Comment: please give more detail.  it sounds like one of your files (probably either urls or views) is still referencing your models.  but we need to see the code.  if this isn't an "academic" question you could always use sqlite.

Comment: I have added more details in the post, Please have a look.

Comment: Please share `settings.py` this will help a lot.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `sqlite3` as your database engine, and run syncdb. Thus django could store your models in file based sqlite database and everything will be ok for you.

This setting could be done from `settings.py`:

```
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.sqlite3',
        'NAME': 'mydatabase'
    }
}
```

Comment: In the Django settings it is called sqlite3 but apart from that I think this answer covers his needs.

Comment: This would be the thing OP wants, what's more to add is that Django can't run without a database if you want to use models.Model or any form of auth, admin interface since Django relies on storing some framework related stuff in a database.

Answer (score 1):

I was thinking [importd](https://github.com/amitu/importd) might be a good fit for what you're trying to do, but according to the [slides/ documentation](http://amitu.com/importd/#17) it assumes SQLite is available.

Answer (score 0):

You must start by disabling most of applications (including admin wich use database for logging users interactions). If you want a simple python website without database (maybe for an other app remote administration), I would encourage you to use any other light-weight framework, as tornado or flask.

Most of django advantages are about the ORM or existing applications which often require a database.

If you know no other framework and want a quick result without loosing too much time learning, I would suggest you to take a look to flask first: http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/quickstart/

If you need performances and a all in one experience with tools to handle you tcp connections and your file handling with async performances, you may want to make your web server with twisted.

But I agree, it will look harder to use.